# Microsoft Teams and Bot Framework V4-how to start a proactive 1:1 conversation from scratch?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to get a v4 bot framework bot (C# SDK) to initiate a 1:1 conversation with a user, and I need to be able to get/create the conversation ID.  I'm calling this:

```
var response = await m_client.Conversations.CreateDirectConversationAsync(new ChannelAccount(aadObjectId: "DB84C737-2161-4A35-B8C3-274B1FA4CF15", role: "bot"),
    new ChannelAccount(role:"user",aadObjectId:"045AD4DB-133B-4C1B-870B-8201B7233625"));

// Construct the message to post to conversation
Activity newActivity = new Activity()
{
    Text = "Hello",
    Type = ActivityTypes.Message,
    Conversation = new ConversationAccount
    {
        Id = response.Id
    },
};

// Post the message to chat conversation with user
await m_client.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(newActivity);
```

Which is coming back as a bad request. If I have a user message my bot first (or look for the ConversationUpdated event when they add the bot), I can save the conversation ID (something like a:1NJglnU1nkB-rqiCw2pQjbwMVViEYxyGxqGr8roBJMwtzzyDt_usg02D4HyaACgen_dOkikceYF3vdQ6kt6UAlxcT-tgCw7H8RWw46lLHBKYpxhkzgmMYJ9kOxiseAZga), but I want to be able to retrieve/generate that for a user without them having to message the bot first, which is what I thought CreateDirectConversationAsync would give me.

I've also tried setting the ID parameters for the user/bot (address@domain) as well as the aad object IDs, but the result is the same.  Is there a way that I can have my bot create a conversation ID for a 1:1 chat from the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I played with it, and that was when there was still a Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Teams package, but that's rolled into the core bot framework now. As a result, I think you'd now look to use:

```
m_client.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync
```

instead of

```
m_client.Conversations.CreateDirectConversationAsync
```

On that overload, the key thing is to set the correct values on the "ConversationParameters" object, *especially* the "Bot", "Members" and "TenantId" properties.

Comment: I'd actually tried that already.  Looked something like this:
````
var response = await m_client.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(new ConversationParameters()
{
 IsGroup = false,
 Members = new List<ChannelAccount> { new ChannelAccount(role: "user", aadObjectId: "045AD4DB-133B-4C1B-870B-8201B7233625") },
 TopicName = "subject1",
 TenantId = "A171D65C-EACE-4781-818C-A7B4FFEFAF1A",
 Bot = new ChannelAccount(aadObjectId: "045AD4DB-133B-4C1B-870B-8201B7233626", role: "bot")
});
````
And the result looks the same (BadRequest)

Comment: Also, the difference between CreateConversation vs CreateDirectConversation seems to just be that the direct version excludes the isGroup flag and the tenantID in the JSON.  Both are hitting exactly the same URI.  Even with the TenantID set though, I'm still not able to create a new conversation ID.

Comment: Try remove the TopicName perhaps - that wouldn't really make sense for Teams.

Comment: Just anther suggestion, and I don't know why this would be different, but it's easy to test - when I've done this, I've always used the Teams user id (i.e. "28:xx"), rather than aadObjectId. Again, just a suggestion...

Comment: Actually, the TopicName was the whole point of this test (to see if I could start named chats), but removing it didn't have any effect. Still getting the same error after removing it...

Comment: TopicName probably would just be ignored from the client, as subsequent calls to createConversation will always return the same conversation.Id (you can only ever have one with a user). I'm guessing the failure is because of AAD Id - I believe you must use the teams user Id